# Printing data from a xml file using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup4 and Requests to scrape a xml page for data however i can't seem to print the results. I don't recieve an error but no data is printed.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "website.com?xml=1"
result = requests.get(url)

content = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

steamID = soup.find_all("x")
print (y)
```

Comment: just change `steamID64` to `steamid64` it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an xml parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "xml")
```